# Database Query Is not working in batch file

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

```
@echo off

set user_name=username
set password=
set sid=sid

@echo select distinct scid, to_char(dlog_on_timestamp,'dd-Mon-YYYY hh:mi:ss') from table where dlog_on_timestamp > sysdate-7; | sqlplus -s %user_name%/%password%@%sid% >> C:\Users\test.txt
```

While running this batch file, > symbol created file sysdate-7. But I need to run the DB query and the result should be stored in test.txt

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes for your shell (`cmd.exe` ?) around the command:

```
@echo "select distinct scid, to_char(dlog_on_timestamp,'dd-Mon-YYYY hh:mi:ss') from table where dlog_on_timestamp > sysdate-7;" | sqlplus -s %user_name%/%password%@%sid% >> C:\Users\test.txt
```